# Ros2 Galactic binary installation on Windows 10: failed to create process

Tags: ros, ros2, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi - I followed the steps here: https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Installation/Windows-Install-Binary.html without any errors. And then attempted to run a test node and received the following error `failed to create process`. Command shell output here:

```
C:\Users\ckr>call C:\dev\ros2_galactic\ros2-windows\local_setup.bat
"[rti_connext_dds_cmake_module][warning] RTI Connext DDS environment script not found (\resource\scripts\rtisetenv_x64Win64VS2017.bat). RTI Connext DDS will not be available at runtime, unless you already configured PATH manually."

C:\Users\ckr>ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
failed to create process
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Running Windows 10 on a Toshiba Satellite. System info here:

```
C:\Users\ckr>systeminfo

Host Name:                 DESKTOP-S69KV9F
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Home
OS Version:                10.0.19043 N/A Build 19043
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Organization:   N/A
Product ID:                00325-80000-00000-AAOEM
Original Install Date:     7/16/2021, 5:21:18 PM
System Boot Time:          7/19/2021, 2:22:20 PM
System Manufacturer:       TOSHIBA
System Model:              Satellite S55-B
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 61 Stepping 4 GenuineIntel ~600 Mhz
BIOS Version:              INSYDE Corp. 2.00, 12/2/2014
Windows Directory:         C:\WINDOWS
System Directory:          C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382954/ros2-galactic-binary-installation-on-windows-10:-failed-to-create-process/) by [ckrobin](https://answers.ros.org/users/78373/ckrobin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-07-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved!

The issue was trying to install the windows debug package: `ros2-galactic-20210616-windows-debug-amd64.zip`
rather than the release package: `ros2-galactic-20210616-windows-release-amd64.zip`.

After installing the release package and trying to run `ros2`, the only error received was a missing python library `packaging`. This should probably be added to the current `python` dependencies list.

This is what is currently on the site for `python` dependencies (https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Installation/Windows-Install-Binary.html#install-dependencies):

```
python -m pip install -U catkin_pkg cryptography empy ifcfg importlib-metadata lark-parser lxml matplotlib netifaces numpy opencv-python PyQt5 pip pillow psutil pycairo pydot pyparsing pyyaml rosdistro setuptools
```

Should instead be:

```
python -m pip install -U catkin_pkg cryptography empy ifcfg importlib-metadata lark-parser lxml matplotlib netifaces numpy opencv-python PyQt5 pip pillow psutil pycairo pydot pyparsing pyyaml rosdistro setuptools packaging
```

Would also recommend adding a line above this install dependencies section to recommend that people first upgrade pip. Python dependency installation (e.g. crytography, etc.) errors out if pip is not up to date.

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

---

Originally posted by [ckrobin](https://answers.ros.org/users/78373/ckrobin/) with karma: 26 on 2021-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-24**:
You really want to post your suggestions on the [ros2/ros2_documentation](https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation) issue tracker.

"no one" will see your answer here (and "no one" in quotes, as of course people will see your suggestions, but not the people who will be in a position to change those pages).